# Modular arithemtic and CRT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve the following congruence:

$71x-1 \equiv  0 \pmod{59367} $

Given that $59367=771 \times 77$, I have previously solved that:

$71x \equiv 1 \pmod{771}$ such that $x=-76$

$71x \equiv 1 \pmod{77}$ such that $x=-13$

I'm trying to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but seem to be getting the wrong answer, if anyone can work this out so I can try and understand where it is that I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: If you could tell us where you are going wrong while using Chinese remainder theorem,we could help you better.Besides,the steps that you took **are** correct,but quite unnecessary in resolving the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the CRT for 1 equation, just find the modular inverse of $71$ in the equation $71x ≡ 1 \pmod{59367}$, that will give you the value of $x$.

Comment: Yes you certainly correct. I was over-complicating it!! Thank you, I got x=48497

Comment: Would I be able to use the CRT (even though it's more complicated) ? Merely for sake of practice?

Comment: No, you may not.There is no logical way to decompose an equation into two to like you did because x mod (a*b) may not equal to (x mod a) and (x mod b). and you can mark the answer correct.

Comment: It **is** true.Consider what those statements mean in the form of standard equation.$59637k+1=71x$.This is equivalent to $(771)(77k)+1=71x$ and $(77)(771k)+1=71x$.

Comment: owh, that's correct. then perhaps crt can used if the numbers are co-prime.

Answer (score 1):

Using the modular inverse is the easiest way to the solution, but it can be found using the CRT. 59367 = 3*7*11*257 = 3*77*257.  71x = 1(mod 3),  71x = 1(mod 77), and  71x = 1(mod 257). Solving these equations for x, you get

X = 2(mod 3)

X = 64(mod 77)

X = 181(mod 257)

Solving the first two equations simultaneously, you get x = 218(mod 231).

Solving this result with the third equation, simultaneously you get the final answer

x = 48497(mod 59367).